# Adds as string instead of number

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

When I add two variables that I initialize as numbers, JS considers them as a string and concatenates them. In a calculation as follows,

```
var p1 = new window.TRIGEO.Point(150, 150);
var p2 = new window.TRIGEO.Point(500, 350);
var p3 = new window.TRIGEO.Point(50, 500);
var medicentre = new Point((p1.x+p2.x+p3.x)/3,(p1.y+p2.y+p3.y)/3);
```

(where Point has x and y as members),`medicentre` is huge =>( 5016683.33 , 50116833.33 ). I do not want this when the answer is actually =>( 233.33 , 333.33 ).

Is there any way to override this behaviour without making the formula too long, cause I have another one, which is at least three lines long. Is this possible without using `parseInt()`?

EDIT:

Point object is the following and that's it!

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

`TRIGEO` is the name of the library I'm writing to visualize all the important points and line segments of a triangle. Sorry for the confusion, I probably should've edited.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I think you mean before accessing each property (`+p1.x + +p2.x`).

Comment: @MikeC. Oh, it returns an object, my bad (thought it was a string) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whilst Parsint as already answered is technically correct, if you want a shorter formula you can trick the casting by making your values positive (as long as you know they aren't going to have non-numberic values

```
var num1 = '1111.11';
var num2 = 2222.22;
var n1plus2 = (+num1)+num2
// n1p2 : 3333.33
```

or both strings:

```
var num1 = '1111.11';
var num2 = '2222.22';
var n1p2 = (+num1)+(+num2);
// n1p2 : 3333.33
```

Comment: should still work, check edit. unless they aren't actually becoming strings

Comment: when was this feature added? I did not know this existed @Washington Guedes !

Comment: using spaces you can drop the paranthesis: `var n1p1 = +num1 + +num2;`

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript doesn't consider them as `string`. You probably execute an operation in the `Point` class and convert them.

```
function A(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var a = new A(1, 1),
    b = new A(2, 2),
    c = new A(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);

alert(c.x + " - " + c.y)
```

This will output `3 - 3` as expected.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the source of a third party library if you are not very very sure about it

Comment: Javascript **does** consider them a string or it wouldn't be concatenating them.

Comment: It isn't `JavaScript` that considers them strings, it's literally the `Point` class that assigns them as `string` type variables inside its implementation. But thanks for the fast downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you might know that this answer doesn't answers the question

Comment: I didn't said you did. The question: "When I add two variables that I initialize as numbers, JS considers them as a string and concatenates them" is flawed. He passes two numbers in a constructor of a class. The class converts them internally to string, and assigns them to `x` and `y` fields. I assume he wrote the `Point` class, ergo, it does answer his question to check the type assignment he does.

Comment: @bogdan.mustiata Javascript considers them strings. Because, yes, they're assigned as strings inside of `Point`. That doesn't change the fact that this doesn't answer the question and suggests that OP alters the code of a 3rd party library. Therefore, you got a downvote. Also, your subtraction example at the end doesn't make sense. Whether they were numbers or strings, you would still `alert` out `3 - 3`.

Comment: Mike, please re-read his question. He literally believes that he initializes them as `number`s, and JS converts them to `string`. Also I don't know if this is a 3rd party lib, or just some code he wrote, since I haven't heard of the Triego lib.

Comment: @bogdan.mustiata Then leave a comment correcting him that the library is doing the converting, not JS. And a quick google search would show that this is a library. As it stands, OP is asking for a way to perform the computation without the use of `parseInt`. Meaning, this still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @bogdan.mustiata No, I do not believe and no, this is not a library. Please read the edited question

Comment: Then with all the respect @Gouthamm4G, there is probably something you're doing wrong, so you're converting the numbers to String: Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/72rrdzgj/

In the case of your code, you should set a breakpoint on the medicentre assignment, and see if the `typeof p1.x` is still a `number`.

Comment: @bogdan.mustiata I found out later that I was assigning the value from a range input element which I presumed to be a number instead of string. So I changed the constructor to include parseInt().